# How can I drag an object with collision detection?

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to create a function in which I can drag a MovieClip which will bump into other MovieClips on the stage without overlapping them. (i.e. the object cannot be dragged over or through other MovieClips).

```
function dragHolder01(event:Event):void{
    if (mouseDownHolder01 == true) {
        for(var m:int = 0;m<blockHolder.numChildren; m++){
            var hitBlock:DisplayObject = blockHolder.getChildAt(m);
            if(movaHolder01.hitTestObject(hitBlock)){
                movaHolder01.x = movaHolder01x;
                movaHolder01.y = movaHolder01y;
                break;
            }
        }
        movaHolder01.startDrag();
        movaHolder01x = movaHolder01.x;
        movaHolder01y = movaHolder01.y;
    }
}
```

---

I think I might have a conceptual solution but I need your help.
I thought that maybe I can limit the "startDrag" to allow for dragging in accordance with the frames progression, i.e. the player will not be able to drag the object more than one pixel for each frame (and so cannot drag the object INTO another by more than one pixel).

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: What have you tried so far, do you have any code to show?  What is the set up of your file, do you have a usable reference to the other objects on stage?

Answer (score 2):

Split this problem into parts. As I see it, the parts are:

- object is left-clicked, call startDrag() on it and have enterFrame() listener ready.
- on every frame check collisions between dragged object and desired scene objects.
- suppose you have collision. What next - how do you handle it? You can just snap it to previous position - this way objects will stuck on slightest contact. Or you may shift collided object by some vector. It might be vector from center of obstacle to the center of collided object (if they both are small.)
- when left button is released, call stopDrag().

If you prefer Box2D, there are other steps:

- turn your movie clips into physical shapes. Don't ask me how - this will not be automatic.
- instead of startDrag() apply some force to dragged object. The more mouse cursor shifts from object, the more force should be. Box2D will resolve collisions and bump objects automatically.

**Update:** how to store previous position

```
var positions:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
var clip:MovieClip = ...; //load your clip somehow

//store position
position[clip] = new Point(clip.x, clip.y);

//read position
var pos:Point = position[clip];

//update position - reuses Point objects to make things somewhat faster
var pos:Point = position[clip];
pos.x = clip.x;
pos.y = clip.y;
//that's all, reference to Point is already in the Dictionary.
```

There is other method. MovieClip is not final class, so it can be inherited and extended with previous position. It is also dynamic, this means you can just insert data on it:

```
clip.prevX = clip.x; //prevX will be created if not exist
clip.prevY = clip.y;
//move clip
```

Comment: That's exactly right... I just can seem to get part 3. I have 1 (drag in enterFrame) and 2 (hit test), but I can't seem to effectively get the dragged object back to previous position. How can I sample the position outside of the collided object?

Comment: To snap object back (simplest version), store previous position associated with the clip (in the Dictionary with MovieClip key, or make wrapper class which will hold MovieClip and extra data.) Or compute said vector based on collided objects' centers. How large your objects are?

Comment: Objects size are varied. My problem is exactly with storing the previous position... I am unfamiliar with the Dictionary or wrapper class.

Comment: Thank you, alxx. I've been able to store the prev position by placing the variables assignment (of the prev position) after the startDrag, within the enterFrame, and the if before the startDrag. The only problem I'm still facing is that if I drag the object too fast, it goes "into" the other object. The dragging stops, but then the dragged object is positioned "on" the collided one. Is there a way around that?

Comment: So it goes back when drag is slow, and don't when drag is fast?

Comment: If drag is too fast, the dragged object gets "stuck" over the collided object. I can drag it back and I can't drag it further in (the desired effect), but it should stop just at the border. of the collided object, not on it (this doesn't happen if I drag slowly).

Answer (score 1):

If you want physical behavior (that is, things bouncing when hit), do not implement it yourself and use a physics engine, such as Box2D. They have several examples of MouseDragged objects (see the MouseDrag of the Test class http://box2dflash.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/box2dflash/Examples/TestBed/Test.as?revision=158&content-type=text%2Fplain).

If you want just non-overlapping objects (depending on the degree of collision detection you want), you could use MovieClip.hitTest() as your collision detection and verify if the object being dragged (at the mouse position), did not hit anything, and if it did, you restore it to the previous position. Please note though, that the mouse can move at any speed within a time-frame, so the dragged object could go through another object if the mouse was moved too fast (you could perform a continuous interpolation of a fixed size to avoid this).

Physical Behavior and Collision Detection are serious mathematical and computer problems, and should not be taken lightly. If you want decent collision and physical behavior, it's a lot less time consuming to get acquainted with a physics engine (that has been used and tested and optimized so many times), than to write your own code to perform that behavior.

If you still don't want to use a Physics Engine, show me your code and I might be able to make it more to your liking (at the cost of some computational time, perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have look at a physic engine such as Box2D: http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid that would take to long to implement on my already existing code. I would just like to use a function that performs this.